# html input returns undefined with express

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express

So I'm learning how to do Node.js with Mysql for the first time. I'm currently following this tutorial(https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-node-js-with-a-database-part-1-3f2461bdd77f) and I'm stuck at the point(before the title 'Setting up Knex') where I run node and when the user inputs their desire username and password in the input. In the tutorial it says it should console.log back the users' username and password but instead I get undefined.

```
Server running on http://localhost:7555
Add user undefined with password undefined
```

I try looking up how to resolve it but I can't seem to have my work. I'm not quite sure if it is express or html that may seem outdated. This is what I have now.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Node Database Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create a new user</h1>
    <form action="/CreateUser", method="post">
        <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="username">
        <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Create user">
    </form>
    <script src="/app.js"><script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
const CreateUser = document.querySelector('.CreateUser')
CreateUser.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const username = CreateUser.querySelector('.username').value
    const password = CreateUser.querySelector('.password').value
    post('/createUser', { username, password })
})

function post(path, data){
    return window.fetch(path, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
}
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const store = require('./store')
const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})
app.post('/createUser', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
        if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
        store.createUser({
          username: req.body.username,
          password: req.body.password
        })
        .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
})

app.listen(7555, () => {
    console.log('Server running on http://localhost:7555')
})
```

Please help, I've been stuck for a few days.

edit: this is where my console.log is at(store.js)

```
module.exports = {
  createUser({ usern-ame, password }) {
    console.log(`Add user ${username} with password ${password}`)
    return Promise.resolve()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your form there is no `class='CreateUser'` in your `<form>` tag. Add the class there.

Also, in your `app.post` there is no `console.log`

The store.js is syntactically incorrect, it should be:

```
module.exports = {
  createUser: function({ username, password }) {
    console.log(`Add user ${username} with password ${password}`)
    return Promise.resolve()
  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't solve my problem sadly ;( 
the console.log is in a file called store.js that app.post calls. I'll edit my original post to have it.

Comment: thanks I tried your change, but it still didn't resolve my undefined issue ;/

Comment: what is being printed now?

Comment: the same thing as before
Server running on http://localhost:7555
Add user undefined with password undefined

Comment: `console.log` the `req.body` before `store.createUser` and paste the content. And also `console.log({username, password})` in app.js before the `post ` call. We need to figure out where the problem is originating

Comment: So I did what you told me and this is what I got: Server running on http://localhost:7555
before store.createUser  {}
Add user undefined with password undefined

seems like the console.log({username, password}) in app.js wasn't printed.

Comment: That means the value is not being captured in the app.js. You really added the class="CreateUser" in the <form> tag? it will be `<form action="/CreateUser" method="post" class="CreateUser">`. Also there is an unexpected comma(,) in your form html

Comment: Yes I did add the tag. I figure it out why it wasn't being capture. I added the name="username" and name="password" to the input tag and it worked :) Thank you for trying to help me I appreciate it!